# Replacing value based on conditional pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do you replace a value in a dataframe for a cell based on a conditional for the entire data frame not just a column. I have tried to use df.where but this doesn't work as planned

```
df = df.where(operator.and_(df > (-1 * .2), df < 0),0)
df = df.where(df > 0 , df * 1.2)
```

Basically what Im trying to do here is replace all values between -.2 and 0 to zero across all columns in my dataframe and all values greater than zero I want to multiply by 1.2

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood the way [pandas.where](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) works, which keeps the values of the original object if condition is true, and replace otherwise, you can try to reverse your logic:

```
df = df.where((df <= (-1 * .2)) | (df >= 0), 0)
df = df.where(df <= 0 , df * 1.2)
```

Comment: You should have the & operator instead of |.  As written, everything will be changed to 0.  I tried to edit, but SO would not allow me to change ONLY the | to &.

Answer (score 0):

where allows you to have a one-line solution, which is great.  I prefer to use a mask like so.

```
idx = (df < 0) & (df >= -0.2)
df[idx] = 0
```

I prefer breaking this into two lines because, using this method, it is easier to read.  You could force this onto a single line as well.

```
df[(df < 0) & (df >= -0.2)] = 0
```

Just another option.